# Fetching a value from an xml doc in coldfusion with a "-"

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I use cfhttp to get an xml doc from a web service, and parse it as:

```
<cfset responseXML = xmlParse(toString(httpResponse.fileContent))>
```

Everything was fine, until I came across one of their xml tags as:

```
<cfset strReturned = #responseXML.POSITION-TITLE.XMLText# >
```

I get a coldfusion error that says invalid construct found, specifying the - as the cause. How can I get this value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using quotes:

`responseXML["POSITION-TITLE"].XmlText`

Comment: Ah so simple. I had previously only thought variable["index"] was for arrays.

Comment: Ben Nadel has a blog post explaining this in more detail. [Accessing XML Nodes Having Names that Contains Dashes](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1894-accessing-xml-nodes-having-names-that-contain-dashes-in-coldfusion.htm)

Comment: And there's the relevant docs: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/About+structures. Don't forget those.